# calling viewPager.setCurrentItem(0) from notification drawer throws null pointer error

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I'm using a Viewpager with 3 fragments and trying to change the fragments from the navigation drawer using **viewPager.setCurrentItem("index value")**.

It works fine when I call **setCurrentItem** method from all the other cases except case 0.

```
    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    switch (position)
    {

        case 0:
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            Toast.makeText(this,"fragment 1",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            break;
        case 1:
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            break;
        case 2:
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
            break;
        default:
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }
}
```

Using setCurrentItem() method in case 0 throws null pointer exception.

Is there an alternate method for this problem.

Projet Source Code
http://www.wikiupload.com/E7VY2NNQHYC8WU3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was throwing null pointer exception and I fixed it by checking if it is null

```
case 0:
     if(viewPager!=null) {
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
      }
      .
      .
      .
```